# How CASE or select if cab be used based on some conistion to fetch data from diffrent table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, grafana

there are two tables suppose (t1 and t2)

based on the constant condition I want to fetch data from different table

txn is a predefined value

I want something like this 
like: if txn=0 (select * from t1;)
else (select * from t2;

used case and when, but I could get data from only one table

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html   - IF your code is in a stored program check syntax if not then you can't use IF in an anonymous code block.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)